# Need help fixing css in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am making something like a landing page.
The page looks okay in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.
However, the divs look completely out of whack in IE (any version).

Can any of you experts take a look at it and suggest any changes?

The URL is : http://anandpinky.com/test.html

Thanks for all your help for this newbie.

Comment: "Act Now OR Die Forever" - wtf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem with your `.showcasebar` `<h1>` tag. Remove `float:right`. It is not needed.  Use `text-align:right` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
.showcasebar ul {
    width: 350px;
}
```

If you float list items in list, give list fixed width.